# Property and synthesize in iOS

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, properties, synthesizer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [@property @synthesize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032826/property-synthesize)

When must I use property and synthesize for an element as NSArray, NSSTring....or IBOutelt as UIButton or UITextFiled?

Comment: Duplicates: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032826/) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140782/) [3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169822/) [4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700296/) [5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394206/when-u-have-to-use-property-and-synthesize-in-iphone-sdk) [...](http://stackoverflow.com/search?page=2&tab=relevance&q=synthesize%20iphone)

Comment: @Mat "This site is not a substitute for the vast amounts of documentation on objective-c already available through search engines."

Well, this is currently the first hit on google for "iOs synthesize", so you should post an answer instead of a comment, or you comment will contradict itself =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A property is used mainly when other objects need to change or access the ivars in your object. Without manually defining getters and setters, or using @property, other objects can't see or change the ivars. Properties are also often used for convenience of memory management, assisting you in preventing memory leaks.

Comment: And @synthesize means the getters and setters are automatically generated.